# How to send Java mail with error trapping and reports

Tags: java, sendmail

My Windows Java  app needs to send individualized email to multiple recipients. The user must provide host, port, username, password, and of course recipient addresses. I'd like there to be meaningful reports if something goes wrong, e.g., "Failed to connect. Check username & password". If connect fails, no attempt to send should be made. Also, Email addresses should be validated as to format, and skipped if invalid.

I've looked at many examples that have helped me to create the working code below. It's doing a fair job of telling the user what was wrong, e.g., host doesn't exist, username or password wrong, etc. but it's inelegant at best.

I'm aware of SendFailedException and expect that it's what I need, but have yet found an example complete and simple enough to show me how to fit it my needs. Examples I've seen so far are either too simple, or too complex and embedded in large projects. I'm hoping someone can tell me if I'm on the right track at all, or how to improve it.

Here's my code (revised 2019 Sep 2):

```
public class SimpleMail2 {
private static String host;
private static String port;
private static String username;
private static String password;
private static String from;

private void sendAction(){
    host =  "smtp.gmail.com"; //"nx.dnslinks.com"; //
    port = "587";
    username = "jagman653@gmail.com"; //eds653@concoursbuilder.us"; 
    password =  "xxxxx"; 
    from = "usere123@concoursbuilder.us";
    String [] recipients = {"usera123@concoursbuilder.us", // Good
                            "userb123@concoursbuilder-us", // Valid according to RFC 822, but deemed INVALID for typical recipients.
                            "userc123concoursbuilder.us",  // Invalid format... no @
                            "userX123@concoursbuilder.us", // Valid format but no such mailbox at concoursbuilder.us
                            "hurt123@aol-com",  // Invalid format
                            "userc123@concoursbuilder.us"}; // Good

    // Prevalidate all recipient addresses
    ArrayList<String> goodAddrs = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Prevalidate email addresses.");
    for(String recip : recipients){
        System.out.println("recip: " + recip);
        boolean isOK = validateEmail(recip); //Valid according to RFC 822, but deemed INVALID for typical recipients.
        if(isOK){
            String msg;
            goodAddrs.add(recip);
            msg = "Good email address: " + recip;
            System.out.println(msg);
        } else {
            String msg;
            msg = " Bad email address: " + recip;
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }
    String[] goodAddrAry = new String[goodAddrs.size()];
    goodAddrAry = goodAddrs.toArray(goodAddrAry);
    int result = senderToAll(goodAddrAry);
    System.out.println("There were " + result + " successful sends and " + (recipients.length - result) + " failures.\n");
}

private int senderToAll(String [] recipients){
    System.out.println("Starting senderToAll\n\n");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", password);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //TLS
    // Note that an authenticator is incorporated in the session instance. 
    Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    Transport transport = null;
    int successfulSends = 0;
    try {
        transport = mailSession.getTransport();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
        String msg = ex.getMessage();
        System.out.println(msg  + "\n");
        Logger.getLogger(SimpleMailDialog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return successfulSends; 
    }
    try{
        if(!transport.isConnected())
            transport.connect();
    } catch ( javax.mail.MessagingException mex){
       String msg = mex.getMessage();
       String msg2;
       if(msg.contains("Unknown SMTP host") || msg.contains("DNS Error")) {
           msg2 =  "MessagingException while trying to connect: Could not connect. Check eMail host name" ;
           System.out.println(msg2);
       } else if(msg.contains("Could not connect to SMTP host")){
           msg2 =  "MessagingException while trying to connect: Could not connect. Check eMail host name & port" ;
           System.out.println(msg2);
       }
       else if(msg.contains("authentication failed") || msg.contains("535")){
            msg2 =  "MessagingException while trying to connect: Authentication failed. Check user eMail address & password.";
            System.out.println(msg2);
       }  else {
            msg2 =  "MessagingException while trying to connect: " + mex.getMessage();
            System.out.println(msg2);
       } 
       return successfulSends; // no sends will be attempted
    }
    for(String recip : recipients){
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        try {
            message.setContent("This is sent to " + recip + " using SimpleMail", "text/plain");
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            String msg2 =  "MessagingException while trying to set content: " + ex.getMessage();
            System.out.println(msg2);
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleMailDialog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        boolean result = true;
        try {
            result = senderToSingle(message, transport, recip, from);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String msg2 =  "Exception while sending to " + recip + "message: " + ex.getMessage();
            System.out.println(msg2);
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleMailDialog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            result = false;
        }
        if(result){
           String msg = "Sent to " + recip;
           System.out.println(msg);
           successfulSends++;
        } else {
           String msg = "NOT Sent to " + recip;
           System.out.println(msg);
        }
   }

    if(transport.isConnected()){
        try {
            transport.close();
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
           String msg = "Failed to close connection";
           System.out.println(msg);
           Logger.getLogger(SimpleMailDialog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
   return successfulSends; 
}


public static boolean senderToSingle(MimeMessage message, Transport transport, String recip, String from) throws Exception{
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from)); 
    InternetAddress[] toAddrs = InternetAddress.parse(recip);
    InternetAddress[] replyToAddrs = InternetAddress.parse(from);
message.setRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddrs[0]);
    message.setReplyTo(replyToAddrs);
    Address[] toRecips = message.getRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO);
    String msg2;
    try {
        transport.sendMessage(message, toRecips);
    } catch (MessagingException ex){
        String msg = ex.getMessage();
        if(msg.contains("Invalid Address") || msg.contains("User unknown")){
            msg2 =  "MessagingException: " + recip + " is an invalid address. ";
            System.out.println(msg2);
            return false;
        } else if(msg.contains("Mailbox unavailable") ){
            msg2 =  "MessagingException:  mailbox unavailable while attempting to send . " + recip ;
            System.out.println(msg2);
            return false;
        } else {
            msg2 =  "MessagingException: " +  msg + " for recipient " + recip ;
            System.out.println(msg2);
            return false;
        }
    }  
    return true;
}


public boolean validateEmail(String email) {
    boolean isValid = false; // this value never used
    try {
        InternetAddress internetAddress = new InternetAddress(email, true); // strict
        internetAddress.validate(); // this throws AddressException if it doesn't meet RFC822 rules
        // There is a "@" since otherwise it would have thrown AddressException
        //Check to be sure it also has a DOT after the @ ... i.e., the most common form of address
        String[] splitArray = email.split("@");
        if(splitArray[1].contains(".")) isValid = true;
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        System.out.println("AddressException in MyJavaUtils validateEmail(). Bad eMail address: " + email);
        return  false;
    }
    return isValid;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleMailDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleMailDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleMailDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleMailDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the dialog */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            SimpleMail2 smt = new SimpleMail2();
            smt.sendAction();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: That's a lot of code... you'll get better answers if you [edit] your question and trim it down to a [mcve] that shows your problem. Actually, what is the problem? What happens when you run the code? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? Check [ask]. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Robert. Actually, I did quite a bit of simplification. But I wanted to show I've made some effort. I find archives are full of overly simplified sendmail examples, balanced by as many overly complex examples. Mine is complete and running. However, I wasn't able to report exactly what was wrong... only "check everything." I'll keep trying.

Comment: I've discovered that the above code performs differently depending on the host. When using nx.dnslinks.net an address that doesn't exist, i.e., no user with that address, transport.sendMessage() throws a MessagingException "Invalid user." In contrast, smtp.gmail.com generates no such exception. Consequently, the user will be led to believe it's been sent until a bounce message arrives in the users email. This is because nx.dnslinks.net has implemented vitaddresstable while smtp.gmail.com has not.

Comment: Oops. No I see that nx.dnslinks.net can only do the MessagingException "Invalid user." when the bad username is on the same host.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using an existing library for this? e.g. http://www.simplejavamail.org

Comment: Thanks, Catchwa. Don't know anything about simplejavamail, but it looks like it's not freeware. My project is provided free to a very small group so I can't afford to buy commercial software. And I have a nagging feeling that what I need can be done with available features in the various free libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a more complete example of SendFailedException usage here:
https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Samples. See Max Spivak's public class transport. For my needs, I had to modify it to do Authentication. Works great, but I'm curious about his including a Thread Sleep after the sendmessage.